# Is it possible to deduce a type of passed generic automatically?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have the next class:

```
open class Repository<TEntity: KeyEntity, TDao: BaseDao<TEntity>>(val dao: TDao) {

    fun insert(entity: TEntity, callback: ActionCallback<TEntity>? = null) {
        InsertAsyncTask(dao, callback).execute(entity)
    }
}
```

When I specify a some DAO type it contains information about `TEntity` type. Is it possible to rewrite the class to I could inherit it providing one type only?

```
class MyRepo : Repository<MyDao>(myDao)
```

Instead of

```
class MyRepo : Repository<MyEntity, MyDao>(myDao)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Kotlin does not do type inference on class declaration level.

But your example could be slightly simplified, and this probably could solve your problem.

Since `TDao` is not used as a type parameter you can remove it from class declaration, and declare implicit type for constructor parameter as `BaseDao<TEntity>` like this:

```
open class Repository<TEntity: KeyEntity>(
    val dao: BaseDao<TEntity>
) {

    fun insert(entity: TEntity, callback: ActionCallback<TEntity>? = null) {
        InsertAsyncTask(dao, callback).execute(entity)
    }
}
```

And finally class declaration could be one type less:

```
class MyRepo : Repository<MyEntity>(myDao)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case we lose information about `dao`'s type. But thank you for explanation, I will know it's impossible in Kotlin at this moment.